# Error no especificado - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, get, internet-explorer

Estoy haciendo una request con XMLHttpRequest, en IE7.

En `onreadystatechange`, gestiono el mensaje a mostrar segun el código de estado. Si el estado es `200`, no se queja. Cuando el estado es `500`, la consola js dice `Error no espcificado`.

Aunque el alert() con el codigo de estado sale bien, aparece el icono de 'error js' en el marco inferior del navegador.

Codigo cliente simplificado:

```
<script>...
 request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    alert("ESTADO:"+request.status);//marca esta linea
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }else if(this.status == 500){
            alert("Error interno del servidor");
        }
    };
...</script>
```

Código servidor simplificado:

```
...
try{
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {
 response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);      
}

try {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(missatge);
        response.flushBuffer();
}catch(IOException e){

}
...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje del navegador se refiere a un error general del javascript de la página, no al control del `request`. Con el código simplificado poco podemos observar, si el navegador no te da pistas de la línea del error, te tocará ir depurando a mano, vete comentando porciones de código hasta que identifiques las líneas que lanzan el error y entonces nos las podrás mostrar si sigues sin averiguar cual es el fallo.

Comment: Depurando a mano sale eso. Como comenté en el codigo, la linea que marca es donde comparo con el '500'. Si quitara el alert(), da error en la linea ..this.status == 500.. Supongo que tiene algo que ver con el servidor, es lo unico que se em ocurre.

Comment: Y ya haz debugueado el código del servidor?

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré la solución.

El error es justamente lo que dice la consola, pero no entra en detalles..me explico:

La propiedad [readyState](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp) tiene 5 valores:

- 0: request not initialized
- 1: server connection established
- 2: request received
- 3: processing request
- 4: request finished and
  response is ready

La propeidad `onreadystatechange` define una función anonima que se ejecuta al cambiar dichos valores.
Entonces, hasta que `readyState no es = 4`, es decir la response está lista, la propiedad `status` digamos que aún no tiene valor. De hecho el error sale 4 veces en la consola.

En conclusión, al intentar comparar el valor de request.status sin estar completa la respuesta, da ese error, por eso hay que añadir ambas condiciones:

```
request.readyState == 4 && request.status == xxx
```

Comment: recuerda que en cuanto te sea posible aceptes tu respuesta para indicar como solucionada tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

- poner en la carpeta del dominio .htacces

```
# Enable cross domain access control
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(1xyz\.com|2xyz\.com)$" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```